# scrapy link extractor adds equal signs to the end of links

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to parse a forum with this rule:

```
rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'page-\d+$')), callback='parse_item', follow=True),)
```

I've tried several approaches with/without r at the beginning, with/without $ at the end of the pattern etc. but every time scrapy produces links ending with equal sign even though there is no = in links neither on the page nor in pattern.

There is an example of extracted links (using also parse_start_url so the start url is here too and yes, I've tried to delete it - it doesn't help):

```
[<GET http://www.example.com/index.php?threads/topic.0000/>,
 <GET http://www.example.com/index.php?threads%2Ftopic.0000%2Fpage-2=>,
 <GET http://www.example.com/index.php?threads%2Ftopic.0000%2Fpage-3=>]
```

If I open in browser or fetch in scrapy shell these links I get wrong pages with nothing to parse but deleting equal signs solves the problem.

So why is it happening and how can I handle it?

EDIT 1 (additional info):

1. Scrapy 1.0.3;
2. Other CrawlSpiders are fine.

EDIT 2:

Spider's code:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request


class BmwclubSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "bmwclub"
    allowed_domains = ["www.bmwclub.ru"]
    start_urls = []
    start_url_objects = []

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'page-\d+$')), callback='parse_item'),)

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        return Request(url = response.url, callback=self.parse_item, meta={'site_url': response.url})

    def parse_item(self, response):
        return []
```

Command to collect links:

```
scrapy parse http://www.bmwclub.ru/index.php?threads/bamper-novyj-x6-torg-umesten-150000rub.1051898/ --noitems --spider bmwclub
```

Output of the command:

```
>>> STATUS DEPTH LEVEL 1 <<<
# Requests  -----------------------------------------------------------------
[<GET http://www.bmwclub.ru/index.php?threads/bamper-novyj-x6-torg-umesten-150000rub.1051898/>,
 <GET http://www.bmwclub.ru/index.php?threads%2Fbamper-novyj-x6-torg-umesten-150000rub.1051898%2Fpage-2=>,
 <GET http://www.bmwclub.ru/index.php?threads%2Fbamper-novyj-x6-torg-umesten-150000rub.1051898%2Fpage-3=>]
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, works fine here. Try updating your `scrapy` version to 1.1.0. Else, give me a link that doesn't work for you.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida updated scrapy - it didn't work but thank you for a try. Also added spider's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because of canonicalization issues.

You can disable it on the `LinkExtractor` like this:

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'page-\d+$',), canonicalize=False), callback='parse_item'),
)
```